# Split string on last occurring underscore

Tags: php, regex, string, split, text-parsing

I've got strings which consist of a label, underscores, and an ID:

- "category_4"
- "office_362"
- "core_market_56"

What I'd like to have are two distinct chunks:

- array("category", 4)
- array("office", 362)
- array("core_market", 56)

I know that I can isolate the numeric value, then turn around and subtract that from the original string, but I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way to do this in one step. Explode's `limit` argument seems close, and I have a feeling there's a regex pattern that could split by only the last underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regex you want

```
(\w*)_(\d*)
```

First matched group is your word, second - number. This is based, of course, on the assumption that number is always in the end and is separated from the word by underscore.

Answer (score 2):

```
$strings = array("category_4","office_362","core_market_56");
foreach($strings as &$string)
{
  preg_match('/(\w*)_(\d*)/', $string, $matches);
  $string = array($matches[1],$matches[2]);
}
print_r($strings);
```

The above will return

```
([0] => Array (
            [0] => category
            [1] => 4)
 [1] => Array (
            [0] => office
            [1] => 362)
 [2] => Array (
            [0] => core_market
            [1] => 56))
```

Answer (score 1):

I figure the most efficient way for *parsing* purposes is to have a **fixed length** numeric field at the end so that you can always count an exact number of characters from the end of the string and know that the rest (minus the separator) will be the text portition.

```
# Example with fixed length numeric portion of 8 digits
$N = 8;
$s = "SomeText_00000001";
$text = substr($s, 0, strlen($s) - $N - 1);
$num = substr($s, -$N);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the technical efficiency part. Unfortunately, I can't fix the length of the IDs but that also wasn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

To split only on the last occurring underscore, use a pattern with a greedy match on "any" characters from the start of the string, then reset the fullstring match just before encountering the last occurring underscore.  This will effectively consume the last underscore only and split the string into two parts at most.  You get exactly what you intend to use, two-element arrays.  `preg_match()` will return three-element arrays, of which the first element is of no use to you.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SJEOF))

```
$strings = ["category_4", "office_362", "core_market_56"];
foreach($strings as $string) {
  var_export(preg_split('/.*\K_/', $string));
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'category',
  1 => '4',
)array (
  0 => 'office',
  1 => '362',
)array (
  0 => 'core_market',
  1 => '56',
)
```